# CouchDB _purge method got HTTP500 { error: 'bad_request', reason: 'Exceeded maximum number of documents.' }

Tags: couchdb

I got the error "{ error: 'bad_request', reason: 'Exceeded maximum number of documents.' }" from CouchDB when I tried to purge 200 docs of CouchDB at once.

But 200 docs didn't exceed the limit. The limit is 1000 docs. I confirmed this by "_purged_infos_limit" method. It replied "1000".

Why I got this error? Shoud I configure any other parameters except "_purged_infos_limit"?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's connected to max_document_id_number parameter mentioned [CDB docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/cluster/purging.html).
I experience the same issue but it's unclear to which section of config file this parameter should belong to. I know it's cluster but CDB sometimes is full of surprises 
Have you resolved your issue, BTW? 
It's quite old and I can't comment now so I post my reply as an answer, please don't mind.